# Logic behind Nokia update availability for "Country variant" models

Tags: lumia, update

Who does approve updates for Country variant? In some cases it looks like it is waiting for approval from all mobile providers, and in other (Lumia 1020) it comes before `O2` finished their testing.

And what is there to be approved in Country variant since these phones don't carry any of the provider nonsense modifications?

[image]

Comment: I think especially without carrier modifications, the country variant has to be tested on all relevant networks to ensure maximum performance (in terms of reliability and data speed).

Comment: @akid tnx for comment. In case of 1020 model this doesn't make much sense since O2 is still testing it on their network. :)

Comment: I agree, I can't explain that. Hence a comment and not an answer ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [this post at Nokia Support forums](http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Software-Updates/Lumia-Amber-update-roll-out-starts/m-p/2054720#M133628) (emphasis mine):

> Phones come in two basic forms:
>
> - Country Variant - this is the standard version of the phone that you might buy independently of your operator. Software for these is **tested and approved by the local Nokia team in that country to ensure that all local specifications are adhered and country-specific needs (including addtional preinstalled apps) are met**.
> - Operator Variants, such as your AT&T-supplied device, go through the same round of testing and approval but this is carried out by your network operator.

Comment: Ok, so update for Country variant can be pushed at any time, independently from network operators?

Comment: I would assume that Nokia/MS still work with local carriers to ensure the phones work on all applicable networks, at least in countries with no carrier-specific variants. That's just my guess, though.